# Php, problem with increasing key value by 1

Tags: php, foreach

I have spent now 2 days figuring out this problem. I'm trying to create voting script which reads .txt file and modifies values inside it. I have problem with foreach part where I try to add +1 in votes of person. 1-5 is id of person, number after | is amount of votes. First output is:

```
Array
(
[0] => 1|2

[1] => 2|6

[2] => 3|8

[3] => 4|3

[4] => 5|10
```

and I want it to add just +1 in last number. But if I try to use increment, I get error: "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot increment/decrement overloaded objects nor string offsets in..."

```
foreach ($file_contents as &$id) {
  if ($id == 2) {
    $id[2]++;
  }
}

print_r($file_contents);
```

I'm still learning PHP and this is weird to me, because just giving "$id[2] = 8" actually modifies that value. Why ++ can't be used? What's way around this?

```
Array
(
[0] => 1|2

[1] => 2|8

[2] => 3|8

[3] => 4|3

[4] => 5|10
)
```

Comment: you mean you want to increment value in this part of the string? `1|2` you'll prolly need to explode it first, then increment the splitted integer, then implode again then write to file again

Comment: Do you know about [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Comment: Why don’t you just use the person id as the array key to begin with, and store just the counter as the value?

Comment: You should use a standardized data format like a csv or json and use the appropriate tools to read and write, modify and the data. In your example you could probably use csv with the `|` as a separator and `fgetcsv()` to read and parse the data.

Comment: Array
(
[ID_OF_PERSON] => 2 
) create array in above format.

Comment: @Ghost. Yes I want to increment value of 1|2 to like 1|3 etc. There was typo in my example it seems with id++. I thought that it would be possible to just $id[2]++ as $id[2] = (any number here) works just fine.

Comment: Exploding worked nicely! That allowed me to use person id as the array. Thanks! Still new to PHP so didn't know how to separate given information so it removes | from there. Now I think I can make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Use json instead. It will make your life much easier.

Json is a text string that can be decode in to an array.
Either a indexed array or an associative array. Associative is preferred in this case in my opinion.

```
$votes = ["1" => 2, "2" => 6, "3" => 8, "4" => 3, "5" => 10];
// Above is an associative array with the same data as your example. 
// The key is the id and the value is the votes.
// To read it from the file use:
// $votes = json_decode(file_get_contents("file.txt"));

$inputVote = 2; // someone voted on person 2.

if(!isset($votes[$inputVote])) $votes[$inputVote] = 0; // if someone voted on a person not already in the array, add the person to the array. 

$votes[$inputVote]++; // increments the votes on person 2.

file_put_contents("file.txt", json_encode($votes));
```

Comment: There was a typo in my example, duh. What I used was $id[2]++ for incrementing for example 2/6 to 2/7. But only $id[2] = (any number here) seems to work and that doesnt serve purpose.

Comment: @bonekuukkeli Yes it will work but it will not be as universal as a json string. Because you use a indexed array it will be harder to keep track of what is what. $id[2] in your case is person 3. In my example $votes[3] is person 3. and I don't need to do any string processing with a `|` in the string I just ++; and it's done.